# how to disable anchor tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery, button, anchor

Here,How to disable this link by using button tab?Is it possible?

```html
 <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <button>click here for go to yahoo</button>
</a>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This HTML is invalid. A `<button>` **must not** appear inside a link. If you want a link that looks like a button then use CSS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Give ids and disable at the run-time.

**HTML**:

```
<a id="disableanchor" href="http://www.google.com">
        <button id="buttononclickdisable">click here for go to yahoo</button>
</a>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('#buttononclickdisable').click(function(){
     $('#disableanchor').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

Or remove the '**click**' event listener.

```
$("#anchorid").off('click');
```

Comment: Disabled is not a valid attribute for the anchor tag.

Comment: `$().prop('disabled', true)` is better than `$().attr('disabled', 'disabled')`. See [javascript - .prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 14):

Surprisingly it is not such a straightforward task since anchor tags do not have a disabled attribute (on the contrary of input tags, select tags, textarea tags, etc.).

The workaround I often use is first to define a class with pointer-events set to none (CSS):

```
.disable-click{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Then I use Jquery (1.0+) to disable/enable the "clickability" of the anchor tag in question by adding/removing the class previously defined:

```
$("#my-a-tag-id").addClass("disable-click");
$("#my-a-tag-id").removeClass("disable-click");
```

Comment: This is a simple yet effective solution that will work just by having JQuery, and can easily be adapted to vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 7):

To essentially disable it, you could likely do:

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

But it would be clearer and more precise if you added a class or id and targeted that in the selector. And what this really does is prevent the action from taking place, it doesn't handle management of *state*, hence making it obvious that the link is not going to work when clicked.

Comment: ..It doesn't works..the anchor tag didn't get disable

Comment: it's still not disabled. but you can prevent the task being executed

Answer (score 4):

You can something like as follow:

Remove the 'href' attribute from the anchor tag ($target will be your anchor tag):

```
$target.removeAttr('href');
```